# Change the code to ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to change this code to ES6, especially I want to use  Object.assign functionality to make it immutable. 
This is what I got

```
function toggle(arr, obj){
    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
      if(arr[i].name ==obj.name){
        arr[i].checked=true;
      }
      return arr;
    }
  }


  var arr = [
  {name: "play", checked:false},
  {name: "swim", checked:false},
  {name: "sing", checked:false}
  ];

  toggle(arr,  {name: "play", checked:false});
```

All it does is  it changes the "checked" property of passed object from false to true. Right now it overwrites my original object, I would like to avoid it.

This is what I have so far:

```
function toggle(arr, obj){
    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
      if(arr[i].name ==obj.name){
        var newArr = Object.assign({}, arr[i], { arr[i].checked: true});
      }

    }
  }
```

Comment: We discourage posts that simply state a problem out of context, and expect the community to solve it. Assuming you tried to solve it yourself and got stuck, it may be helpful if you wrote your thoughts and what you could not figure out. It will definitely draw more answers to your post. Until then, the question will be voted to be closed / downvoted.

Comment: @Cerbrus thank you for feedback, I just did not like  my solution so much that I did not share it. I added it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in the following way

```js
var arr = [
  {name: "play", checked:false},
  {name: "swim", checked:false},
  {name: "sing", checked:false}
  ];

//toggle(arr,  {name: "play", checked:false});

arr = arr.map((a) => {
  return a.name != "play" ? a : Object.assign(a, {checked : true});
})

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: such a beautiful solution! Thank you for the help! @marvel308